# Backbone js issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js

Hi I created employee listing application using backbone js. application shows the list of employees as a landing page, application provides all CRUD operations with respect to employees.

The application is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, But in IE i am facing caching problem.

From the landing page i am redirecting the user to add employees. after adding the employee if user come back to listing page, the page is still showing the old data (in chrome/ firefox updated data is showing in the landing page). every time I need to clear cache for verifying the data. Is there any way to achieve this in IE.

Comment: Do you debug your app with Developer Tools in IE9? Also, get any errors?

Comment: I am using IE 10 in my machine, I debug my application but i dnt see any errors.

Comment: Do you set no-cache headers?

Comment: How do you get data for listing page? With ajax get request? IE caches requests quite eagerly as default behavior.

Comment: In the listing page, I am using backbone fetch to get the data. @Sergey: how can I set no-cache headers?

Comment: @Sergey: I have added {cache:false} in backbone fetch. issue resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @user1987806 - did you try my solution?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a IE ajax caching problem that is not specific for Backbone.js, you should add:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Comment: Yep, this will fix the issue. Had the same experience.